# I need help simultaneously moving the same file type in multiple folder from one subdirectory to another

Tags: command-line, files, mv

Example:
I have 3 folders A, B, C

in each folder(A, B, C) there is a subdirectory called T1.

In this subdirectory called T1, there is a file name called T1.nii.gz.

I want to simultaneously move with one command this T1.nii.gz from the T1 subdirectory to the parent directory in each folder A, B, C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` with `-execdir`:

```
$ find -path '*/T1/T1.nil.gz' -execdir mv -t .. {} \;
```

`-execdir` will change the working directory before exec the command. Next, you supply `mv` with the target directory parent.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well!